# Stripe - android java

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I'm integrating stripe in android java. Can anyone help me sample stripe code in java.
As I'm new to kotlin.

Using default stripe classfor add card "PaymentMethodsActivityStarter"

I'm unable to get response in onActivityResult

Comment: You should start with [the official sample](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic) and then post any specific questions with the particular code and error traces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must look at the code carefully, analyze it and then proceed. If you concentrate, it will become simple for you in no time. Let's go through an example:

```
class MyApp : Application() {
```

We know that this is a class, and its name is MyApp. A quick Google search would tell you that the `:` here just means that the class is extending whatever's on the right of it. Therefore the corresponding Java code should be

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
```

Now we go to the next line

```
override fun onCreate() {
```

States that an *override* tag is involved - a method is being overridden. **fun** in Kotlin means the following should be a function name. Once again, a Google search away. We see that it has no parameters, and no returns. Now you can make the Java code

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
```

Now we move on

```
super.onCreate()
```

Which is calling the superclass method, same in Java.

```
PaymentConfiguration.init(applicationContext,"pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx")
```

I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but I can see that some form of `init` is being called. Parameters are a Context of some sort and a String. A Google search told me that `init` is basically calling the consturctor of a class. Therefore I can immediately try out

```
new PaymentConfiguration(getApplicationContext(), "pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx");
```

If that doesn't work, then Google more to understand what the code *means* instead of searching for a *specific* Java equivalent. If you still have problems, then post on here again with examples and some code and include the solutions you have tried and offer thoughts on what you think the issue could be. This is how we become better programmers that can adapt to and overcome problems.